# In Memoriam: Carl Weathers

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Dead at 76](https://www.cbssports.com/boxing/news/carl-weathers-dead-at-76-beloved-actor-for-his-role-as-apollo-creed-in-the-rocky-franchise-passes-away/), peacefully in his sleep on February 1st, 2024.

Perhaps best known for his breakout role of Apollo Creed in the *Rocky* films, he was of course also Dillon in *Predator* and Greef Karga in *The Mandalorian*, among many other acting and voice roles.

Answer (score 13):

This is the way.

May you be in good hands, maybe even magic ones.

[image]